# Achar a última posição da matriz

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Estou fazendo um jogo no pygame e preciso saber a última posição da matriz para a movimentação dos inimigos.

Tem que ser de acordo com o tamanho da matriz, ou seja, a última coluna e a primeira coluna da matriz tem que colidir com as bordas do mapa.

Esse é o meu código:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit
from random import randint
#define os parametros do canhao
def Canhao(C, x, y):
  R = []
  for i in range(len(C)):
    a = C[i][0] + x
    b = C[i][1] + y
    R.append((a, b))
  return(tuple(R))
#variaveis
T = []
C = ((0,15), (4,5), (12,5), (15,0), (18,5), (26,5), (30,15))
XC = 460
YC = 400
CorFundo = (0, 0, 0)
lar = 30
esp = 5
alt = 30
xp = 330
yp = 380
movx, movy = 5,5
direcao = 1
y = 0
#criando a matriz
j = 0
while j < 5:
  i = 0
  while i < 12:
    o = (10+i*(lar+esp), 10+j*(alt+esp), (0, 180-j*20, 255-j*20), (0, 0, 127))
    T.append(o)
    i = i + 1
  j = j + 1
TiroAtivo = False
#iniciando
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
tela = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption('Space invaders')
#loop infinito
fim = False
while not fim:
  pygame.display.flip()
  tela.fill((0,0,0))
#movimentacao## usar o len(T) para testar se a movimentacao chegou no fim da tela
  if direcao == 1:
      movx += 5
  if movx == 280:
    direcao = 2
    movx -= 5
    movy += 5
  if direcao == 2:
    movx -= 5
  if movx < 0:
    direcao = 1
    movy += 5
    movx += 5
#desenha o canhao
  pygame.draw.polygon(tela, (50,130,50), Canhao(C, XC, YC), 0)
#desenha os inimigos
  for i in range(len(T)):
    pygame.draw.rect(tela, T[i][2], (movx+T[i][0], movy+T[i][1], lar, alt), 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(tela, T[i][3], (movx+T[i][0], movy+T[i][1], lar, alt), 2) 
#colisao
  for i in range(len(T)):
    if movx+T[i][0] <= xp <= movx+T[i][0]+lar and movy+T[i][1] <= yp <= movy+T[i][1]+alt:
      del(T[i])
      xp = 0
##      yp = 0
      TiroAtivo = False
      break
  if yp < 5:
    TiroAtivo = False
#desenha o tiro
  if TiroAtivo:
    pygame.draw.circle(tela, (127, 90, 90), (xp, int(yp)), 3, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(tela, (127, 90, 90), (xp, int(yp)+3), 3, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(tela, (127, 90, 90), (xp, int(yp)+6), 3, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(tela, (127, 90, 90), (xp, int(yp)+9), 3, 0)
    yp = yp - 10
#movimentacao do canhao
  Teclas = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  if Teclas[K_LEFT]:
    XC = XC - 10
  if Teclas[K_RIGHT]:
    XC = XC + 10
  if Teclas[K_SPACE] and TiroAtivo == False:
    xp = XC + C[3][0]
    yp = 380;
    TiroAtivo = True
#tela de game over
  if len(T) == 0:
    # definindo o texto
    fonte_Arial = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 60)
    texto = fonte_Arial.render("Game over!",1,(255,255,255))
    # copiando o texto para a superfície
    tela.blit(texto, [200, 150])
  time_passed = clock.tick(30)
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
      fim = True
pygame.display.quit()
```

Eu estou usando uma variável para movimentação que é a `movx` e `movy`, só que quero mover de acordo com a primeira e a última coluna da matriz.

Por exemplo, se a última coluna for destruída, a penúltima passa a ser a última e a movimentação continua até o final da tela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atualmente o seu número de movimentação máximo para direita está fixo em 280; Você precisa calcular esse valor dinamicamente usando o inimigo que está mais à direita como base.

700 é a largura da tela, então, troque a linha

```
if movx == 280:
```

por

```
if movx > (700 - max(inimigo[0] for inimigo in T) - lar):
```